# Eclipse + Android + JUnit test references android.os class = NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

I have a custom timer that extends android.os.CountDownTimer. I have a test in the test project (standard Android/Eclipse project config) that tests the custom Timer. When I run this test, I get:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/CountDownTimer
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:698)

You get the idea. Can I not run code that references android code code in junit test?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because it isn't possible to test Android's resources with JUnit without further instructions. You have to instrument your project first. This tutorials and the following describes this procedure very well:

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/11/controlling-instrumentation.html
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/11/junit-in-android.html

Here is an explained code snipplet of another test project:
http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/junit-test-example.html

And here you can find the answer on Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps

Comment: he is not resting a resource and is in fact using android test instrumentation per his original question wording..

Hence me asking how he initialized the custom class as that would be the starting point for tracking down the errors